# Selenium with PYthon - Why do fixtures make my tests slower?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, automated-tests

I am using **Selenium** with **Python** to *automate* tests for my company.

Currently I have a suite of 168 tests, they all begin with the same 25 lines of code. Because of this I created a **fixture** for those steps to be performed in the beggining of every test and then just run trough the particular steps of every test, they all pass normaly but it takes twice as long.

Can anyone tell me the reason of this or how to fix it?